# How do I show parts of a string?

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

```
@echo off
set keys=_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
```

from keys above, command `echo !keys:~1,1!` output `A`, command `echo !keys:~4,1!` output `D`.

my question:

How do I echo `CDEF`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I echo `CDEF`?

You are using the correct expression, you just need to change it a little:

```
echo !keys:~2,5!
```

Should do the trick. Start at 2 and end at 5.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [variable substring - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)

Comment: Thanks much! for ur help